# How to find bs4 XML attribute values with BeautifulSoup by identifying attribute by regex in any XML depth?

Tags: python, regex, xml, beautifulsoup

I have the following bs4 element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
    <l2 attribute2="Output"><s3><Cell cell_value2="384.01"/></s3></l2>, 
    <l1><s3 attribute1="Cost"><s4><Cell cell_value1="2314.37"/></s4></s3></l1>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
```

I want to extract all the attribute values like this:

```
["Output", "Cost"]
```

My question is: How can I achieve this with regex `re.compile(r'^attribute[0-9]$')` and in a situation where the `attribute*` can be situation either on the first tag (e.g. `l1` or `l2`) or it can be "deeper" such as in `s3` or other arbitrary depth)?

I can do this if the attributes have the same name or if they are in the same depth level with different names - but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
    <l2 attribute2="Output"><s3><Cell cell_value2="384.01"/></s3></l2>, 
    <l1><s3 attribute1="Cost"><s4><Cell cell_value1="2314.37"/></s4></s3></l1>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

r = re.compile(r"^attribute\d+")

out = []
for tag in soup.find_all(lambda tag: any(r.search(a) for a in tag.attrs)):
    for attr, value in tag.attrs.items():
        if r.search(attr):
            out.append(value)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['Output', 'Cost']
```